# Validate a datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid

I try to validate a datagrid in order to disable or enable a save button.
I would like, in the code behind, to be able to know if there are an error in my datagrid.  For that, I've found a function that allows me to know is my datgrid is valid :

```
private bool HasError(DataGrid dg)
{
    bool errors = (from c in
         (from object i in dg.ItemsSource
          select dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(i))
          where c != null
          select Validation.GetHasError(c)
          ).FirstOrDefault(x => x);
    return errors;
}
```

I binded the event `BeginningEdit` and `CellEditEnding` in my code behind :

```
private void DataGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
{
    ((MainViewModel)this.DataContext).SubVM.SaveButtonIsEnabled = false;
}

private void dg_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (HasError(sender as DataGrid))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
    }
    else
    {
        ((MainViewModel)this.DataContext).SubVM.SaveButtonIsEnabled = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Ok");
    }

}
```

So the trick is to start on the basis that the user input is false and invalidate the save button.

When the user finish editing, I can (maybe) enable the save button.

The problem is that the `CellEditEnding` is raised *before* validation.

```
Ok
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '-78.2' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=Version; DataItem='Reference' (HashCode=64396947); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException
 à System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
 à System.Number.ParseUInt32(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
 à System.String.System.IConvertible.ToUInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
 à System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
 à MS.Internal.Data.SystemConvertConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
 à System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

So, before the validation, my datagrid is valide. And after the validation throws an exception (exptected behavior).

How to achieve that I want ?
Are there an other event which is raised when after validation ?

Comment: You can try CellValueChanged instead, this should run only after the cell v alue has changed, pending the validation.

Comment: Unfortunately, CellValueChanged doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the `CellEditEnd event`

```
((DataGrid)sender).Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
{
    try
    {
        // Code
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException) { }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
});
```